# Rewrite Entity Framework LINQ query into T-SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql

How can I rewrite the following Linq query into normal T-SQL?

```
var list = (from t in context.ParentTable
            where t.ChildRecords.Count == t.ChildRecord.Count( c => c.BooleanColumn )
            select t).ToList();
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: By taking a look at the sql generated by EF?

Comment: Not exactly friendly, hoping for something my eyes can look at without losing sight..

Comment: @Morgs Huh what do you mean with that? There is logging in EF that tells the statement. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Hecl, if you remove the ToList and assign the query to a variable, the tooltip during debugging shows the SQL. It should be standard procedure to check all queries for decent SQL ;) EF fully supports this.

Comment: I managed to get the T-SQL generated using Express Profiler, but obviously EF generates complicated queries so looking for something easier to understand...Busy looking at answer  by @juharr below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, but you'll need to determine the relationship between the `ParentTable` and `ChildRecord` tables to make it work, I'm just guessing at the `cr.ParentTableId = pt.ParentTableId` part.

```
select pt.*
from ParentTable pt
where not exists 
(select 1 
 from ChildRecord cr 
 where cr.ParentTableId = pt.ParentTableId
       and cr.BooleanColumn = 0)
```

On a side note the Linq could be changed to the following instead.

```
var list = (from t in context.ParentTable
            where t.ChildRecords.All(c => c.BooleanColumn)
            select t).ToList();
```

Comment: that's not T-SQL as requested

Comment: @Phil And exactly which part isn't T-Sql?

Comment: The color coding part of Sql snippet :D j.

Comment: @juharr, thanks your query returns same results as EF when I replace `not exists` with `exists`. Much appreciated...

Comment: @Morgs That's odd as I would expect that to give different results.

Comment: @juharr.  Apologies - I was talking rubbish :)